# Intreceptor in spring

Tags: spring

I want know about, from where the `onsave()` method gets arguments?
Example:

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method should come from hibernate interceptor interface (`org.hibernate.Interceptor`).Spring may provides some built-in beans that implements this interface .

This method is supposed to be called when an new entity is first saved by the hibernate session. For example , suppose you map the EMPLOYEE table to the employee object and you create a new employee record using the following codes:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("Peter");
employee.setJoinDate(new Date());
employee.setExtNumber(1234);
/*seesion refer to the Hibernate session*/
session.save(employee);
```

Hibernate will then generate the following INSERT SQL :

```
insert into EMPLOYEE (NAME, JOIN_DATE , EXT_NUMBER) values ("Peter" , to_date('2011-6-20') , 1234)
```

Before the above SQL is issued to the DB , and if there an interceptor enable , hibernate will call onSave() method with the following parameters:

- entity : The employee reference that is being saved
- id    :  PK of the new employee  record
- state  : Arrays containing the values of different fields for the INSERT SQL (i.e. Array
  containing the value "Peter" , new Date() , 1234)
- propertyNames : Arrays containing the name of the columns for the INSERT SQL (i.e Array containing the string "NAME" , "JOIN_DATE" , "EXT_NUMBER")

Comment: Thanks Ken.............I want to know one thing.if propertyNames couldn't able to get the array containing coloumns properly,What will be the pbm their?